# Custom python scripts in installation only updates when restarting blender

Tags: python, scripting

I'm having a lot of fun creating my own python package for blender.
But I have to restart blender every time i edit the packages for it to force reload.

I have searched without luck on how to force update these files. I've tried with `from importlib import reload` but it doesn't work.

I think it doesn't work because my custom script is installed in the blender installation folder:

```
Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\python\lib\site-packages\myPackage
```

What can I try instead?

Comment: Try `bpy.ops.script.reload()` in the python console.  Make sure that site packages is in `sys.path`

Comment: Bpy ops reload didn't work - i tried moving the package into the addon folder. Calling the reload() function said my package lacked addon-enabled. Have you tried this error?

Comment: Not much to go on here. If your module is named for instance `your_module` and is imported `import your_module`  then `importlib.reload(your_module)` should  reflect changes, same as using `imp.reload(your_module)`

Comment: thanks not sure why it wont work